# Payment through Braintree merchant account

Tags: ios, braintree

Is there a way I can process transaction from the master merchant account instead of the customer card? I'm planning to offer redeem points so I would need this.

I'm using marketplace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you need more help, please [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

If you want to send money to your submerchants, there are a couple of ways you can do that.

The first is to not charge them your normal service fees until the amount not charged matches the amount you want to send. This is basically like "store credit" where they can only use their balance to pay the service fees.

The second is to keep a corporate credit card on file as a customer payment method, and charge the corporate card to the sub merchant account to send them money.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I also thought about the second option. Just to make sure if I have a lot of transactions per day that won't block my card and there isn't any card limits as such on a corporate cr card ? Or is it something that my bank may have an issue ?

Comment: If you have more questions, I recommend you reach out to our support team at the link in my answer. You're not really asking a programming question at this point, so Stack Overflow isn't really the best place.