# Braintree marketplace - What happens if Master Merchant do charge client at time time of sale, but has to pay to submerchant

Tags: php, braintree

I have implemented PHP braintree API in a project, I want to use Marketplace api for the same.

Now, we have promotional events and we do not charge client, but we have to pay amount to sub-merchant who has delivered goods.

So below is the code to add service fees, which is clear that at the time of sale we have to add sub-merchant id for merchantAccountId, amount will be payment charged from client, what is paymentMethodNonce?

```
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
  'merchantAccountId' => 'provider_sub_merchant_account',
  'amount' => '10.00',
  'paymentMethodNonce' => 'nonce-from-the-client',
  'serviceFeeAmount' => "1.00"
));
```

Another query is, at the time of sale we have to pass credit card details of the client? What if client is already in vault ? 
Below is another code from Braintree document with creditCard details

```
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(
  array(
    'amount' => "100",
    'merchantAccountId' => "blue_ladders_store",
    'creditCard' => array(
      'number' => "4111111111111111",
      'expirationDate' => "12/20",
    ),
    'options' => array(
      'submitForSettlement' => true,
      'holdInEscrow' => true,
    ),
    'serviceFeeAmount' => "10.00"
  )
);
```

If we do not add creditCard number and have to pay sub-merchant then how can that be done.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Payment through Braintree merchant account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670397/payment-through-braintree-merchant-account)

Comment: I work at Braintree. Please take a look at the question linked above, it describes ways to send money to your sub merchants. If you're still having trouble, I recommend you [call or email the Braintree support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) if you can't find what you need in the [getting started](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/guides/marketplace/overview) or [marketplace](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/start/overview) guides.

Comment: @agf - Is it possible to transfer amount to two sub-merchant for a single transaction ?

Comment: No, it's not. You'll have to run two separate transactions if you want to send money to two separate sub-merchants.

Comment: @agf Consider the scenario, payment is authorized before a week without sub merchant, now at the time of settling we know the sub merchant but how to add sub merchant details at the time of settling the payment as we pass only transaction id to settle.

Comment: Please [call or email the Braintree support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/). You have to choose which merchant account to charge at the time of authorization, you can't change it at settlement time.